# Using WITH in mdx to retrieve row names

Tags: mdx

I am executing the following MDX query in SSMS, which I have got from Profiler:

```
SELECT {
    [Measures].[Dollar Amount],
    [Measures].[Transaction Count]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Retail Sales Date].[Month].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  
FROM [Retail Sales Cube] 
WHERE ([Geography].[Retail Sales Location].[Country Name].&[Australia],[Retail Category].[Retail Category].[All]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

This produces the following results (snippet only):

[image: MDX Query Result 1]

The rows are months, and because of the method of retrieval, I need the months to also be displayed in a column.

So I tried this:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [TheDate] AS [Retail Sales Date].[Month].CurrentMember.Name
SELECT {
    [TheDate],
    [Measures].[Dollar Amount],
    [Measures].[Transaction Count]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Retail Sales Date].[Month].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  
FROM [Retail Sales Cube] 
WHERE ([Geography].[Retail Sales Location].[Country Name].&[Australia],[Retail Category].[Retail Category].[All]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

which would be fine, except that it also shows rows where there are null values, as follows:
[image: MDX query 2]

I know there is NONEMPTY, but I don't know where I would put it. How can I get rid of the empty rows?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following expression would do the trick:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [TheDate] AS 
    IIF( !isEmpty( [Dollar Amount] )
         [Retail Sales Date].[Month].CurrentMember.Name,
         null
    )
```